# Django: reference context variable in an {% if %} block

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates

I'm working on a Django project and editing a base template which the rest of the views inherit from. I have a context variable generally in this format:

```
context = {
    'metadata': {
        'data1': value,
        # etc
    },
    'data': {
        'value1': True,
        'value2': False,
        # etc
    },
}
```

I've been trying to add tags based on if the values in 'data' are true/false like so:

```
{% if data.value1 is True %}
     {% load some_module %}
{% endif %}
{% if data.value2 is True %}
     {% load something_else %}
{% endif %}
```

My problem is that even if `data.value1` is `False` the template tries to load the packages in that `if` block resulting in broken pages. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Can you not reference context variables like that? Am I just using the `if` block wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

UPDATE:
I'm trying to conditionally load some of the tracking tags in Django-Analyical based on whether the project has been configured with the necessary ID's in the settings file.

The actual code in my view is

```
{% block analyticsscripts %}
      {% if analytics.analytical %}
        {% load analytical %}
      {% endif %}
      {% if analytics.clickmap %}
        {% load clickmap %}{% clickmap %}
      {% endif %}
      {% if analytics.clicky %}
        {% load clicky %}{% clicky %}
      {% endif %}
      {% if analytics.crazyegg %}
        {% load crazy_egg %}{% crazy_egg %}
      {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And a sample of the actual code in the context processor is:

```
context['analytics'] = {
            'analytical': bool('analytical' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS),
            'clickmap': bool(settings.CLICKMAP_TRACKER_ID),
            'clicky': bool(settings.CLICKY_SITE_ID),
            'crazyegg': bool(settings.CRAZY_EGG_ACCOUNT_NUMBER),
            'gauges': bool(settings.GAUGES_SITE_ID),
            'googleanalytics': bool(settings.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_JS_PROPERTY_ID),
            'gosquared': bool(settings.GOSQUARED_SITE_TOKEN),
            }
```

which references some of these values in the settings file for the Django project (set at `False` by default until they get specified).

```
CLICKMAP_TRACKER_ID = False
CLICKY_SITE_ID = False
CRAZY_EGG_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = False
GAUGES_SITE_ID = False
GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_JS_PROPERTY_ID = False
GOSQUARED_SITE_TOKEN = False
HOTJAR_SITE_ID = False
HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID = False
INTERCOM_APP_ID = False
```

Comment: It would be more succinct to just say `{% if data.value1 %}`, but your code should work correctly as written. Are you sure that your context is being passed correctly to your template, and that the value is indeed False for some of your data?

Comment: You could display all variables available in a template temporarily with `{% debug %}` (DEBUG must be True for it to work).

Comment: Can you share the view code?

Comment: @ScottWoodall i updated the question with snippets of actual code from my project, Thanks!